# Dynamic nested json string to java object using jackson

Tags: java, json, object, nested, jackson

i have trouble in parsing json

I have a nested json string, i need to convert to java object , the string look like this, i want to ask how to handle this nested dynamic json using jackson, how to decode dynamic nested json string

```
{

"resultCode": "0",
"dataObject": [
    {
        "lastSyncDate": "20140101000000",
        "count": 2,
        "refType": "ADO",
        "update": [
            {
                "artist": "C",
                "albumTitle": "道",
                "productTitle": "道",
                "thumbnail": "http://w.com/mposter/album/m/VACL00020880A_m.jpg",
                "lastSyncDate": "20140425120159",
                "refId": "VACL00214522"
            },
            {
                "artist": "楊",
                "albumTitle": "學",
                "productTitle": "美",
                "thumbnail": "http://m.jpg",
                "lastSyncDate": "20140324161831",
                "refId": "VACP00168673"
            }
        ],
        "delete": [ ]
    },
    {
        "lastSyncDate": "20140101000000",
        "count": 8,
        "refType": "PAT",
        "update": [
            {
                "artist": "方",
                "thumbnail": "http://t.com/moov/images/profile/PAT/8/70/00021870_tn_1_s.jpg",
                "lastSyncDate": "20140201010203",
                "refId": "00021870"
            },
            {
                "artist": "楊",
                "lastSyncDate": "20140328120831",
                "refId": "00000125"
            },
            {
                "artist": "陳",
                "thumbnail": "http://s.jpg",
                "lastSyncDate": "20140328185030",
                "refId": "00017704"
            }
        ],
        "delete": [ ]
    },
    {
        "lastSyncDate": "20140101000000",
        "count": 4,
        "refType": "PAB",
        "update": [
            {
                "artist": "陳",
                "albumTitle": "The Key",
                "thumbnail": "http:/m.jpg",
                "lastSyncDate": "20140603143528",
                "refId": "VAUN00031629A"
            },
            {
                "artist": "何",
                "albumTitle": "梁",
                "thumbnail": "http://m.jpg",
                "lastSyncDate": "20140603143528",
                "refId": "VAEA00003170A"
            },
            {
                "artist": "何",
                "albumTitle": "艷",
                "thumbnail": "http://m.jpg",
                "lastSyncDate": "20110603151452",
                "refId": "VAEA00003179A"
            }
        ],
        "delete": [ ]
    },
    {
        "lastSyncDate": "20140101000000",
        "count": 4,
        "refType": "PP",
        "update": [
            {
                "chiName": "其",
                "engName": "Other",
                "lastSyncDate": "20140130010203",
                "chiAuthor": "",
                "engAuthor": "",
                "refId": "PP1000000003"
            },
            {
                "chiName": "演",
                "engName": "E演",
                "thumbnail": "http://s.jpg",
                "lastSyncDate": "20140126010758",
                "chiAuthor": "專",
                "engAuthor": "Recommended",
                "refId": "PP1000000040"
            },
            {
                "chiName": "日本派台歌",
                "engName": "Japan New Releases",
                "lastSyncDate": "20140126010758",
                "chiAuthor": "",
                "engAuthor": "",
                "refId": "PP1000000057"
            },
            {
                "chiName": "9",
                "engName": "9",
                "thumbnail": "http://s.jpg",
                "lastSyncDate": "20140126010203",
                "chiAuthor": "專",
                "engAuthor": "Recommended",
                "refId": "PP1000000048"
            }
        ],
        "delete": [ ]
    }
]

}
```

Comment: please help  me , the hard part is the field of Update is not fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **only** need to reproduce the structure of the `json` using java class structure. For instance, for your case:

```
    public class Result {
        String resultCode;
        List<DataObject> dataObjects;
        <GETTERS & SETTERS>
    }

    public class DataObject {
        String lastSyncDate;
        int count;
        String refType;
        List<Update> updates;
        List<Delete> deletes;
        <GETTERS & SETTERS>
    }

    public class Update {
        String artist;
        String albumTitle;
        String productTitle;
        String thumbnail;
        String lastSyncDate;
        String refId;
        <GETTERS & SETTERS>
    }

    public class Delete {
        String refId;
        <GETTERS & SETTERS>
    }
```

I assumed that Delete class only contains the refId. With this structure, you'll be able to map the json to an object of the class Result without any problems doing:

```
    byte[] jsonData = <YOUR JSON>
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Result result = objectMapper.readValue(jsonData, Result.class);
```

Comment: ok, but the number of field in "Update" is different in each json object, how to hande it??

Answer (score 2):

Since the field of Update is not fixed, use map instead of the Update class.

```
    public class Result {
        String resultCode;
        List<DataObject> dataObject;
        <GETTERS & SETTERS>
    }

    public class DataObject {
        String lastSyncDate;
        int count;
        String refType;
        List<Map<String, String>> update;
        List<String> delete;
        <GETTERS & SETTERS>
    }
```

Assume that update only contains String values.

```
    String jsonData = "YOUR JSON";
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Result result = objectMapper.readValue(jsonData, Result.class);
```

Comment: Thx,  more details on Map class ok??? any getting or setting function need to code in the map class???

Comment: and How to code getting and setting in the superclass in order to get value from sub class

Comment: for update: private List<Map<String, String>> getUpdate() {return update;}  private void setUpdate(List<Map<String, String>> update) {this.update = update;}. Just like other fields.